# Raspberry Pi NAS read speed slower than write speed

Tags: nas, home-networking, raspberry-pi, samba

i made a DIY NAS using a raspberry pi 4B and a 2TB external drive, shared the drive using samba but can't figure out why the copying from the shared drive is slower compared to when i'm saving to this drive

Involved Equipment:

Raspberry Pi 4B (gigabit capable/Linux/Basic Samba setup)

WD Usb 3.0 2TB (EXT4/connected to the raspberry pi using the USB 3.0 port)

Gigabit Switch TPLink LS1005G (basic unmanaged gigabit switch)

Desktop PC (gigabit capable/Windows/tried on both SSD and HDD same copy speed)

Anyway i mapped everything and its working, but i'm stumped why the read speed is slower than write speed. even bought the gigabit switch and there was minimal improvement from the ISP provided router

Raspberry Pi to PC 30 MB/s average

PC to Raspberry Pi 100 MB/s average

-edit just to add some more info. here's the result of of hdparm
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo hdparm -tT /dev/sda1

/dev/sda1:
Timing cached reads:   1446 MB in  2.00 seconds = 723.07 MB/sec
Timing buffered disk reads: 324 MB in  3.01 seconds = 107.60 MB/sec

Answer (score 0):

That is very similar to this question:
https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/101264/raspberry-pi-4-slow-read-speed-but-high-write-speed-over-network-from-pc

There are potential issues with the controller on your USB drive not fully supporting xHCI on the Pi 4. https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=245931

Comment: hi thanks for answering, unfortunately adding quirks to the drive made no difference to the transfer speed